# How to search Stack Exchange Game Development

Tags: discussion, search

I am being stupid?  I cannot find an icon or box to search the site.  The closest I got was just now when I started to type the title of this post.

Comment: Good news! We have a help page just for that! [How do I search?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the search box at the very top of the desktop site:

[image: Screenshot indicating the search box at the top of the page]

On mobile, you can touch the magnifying glass icon next to the "All Questions" text:

[image: Screenshot of mobile website]

And in the Android app it's again located at the top of the question list:

[image: Screenshot of Android app]

As Alexandre Vaillancourt points out, [we also have a help page with more information about using the search feature](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Comment: Is there a version of the search tool that does not give pixelated results?